# Product image box missing under WooCommerce admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommere 3.6.1. I wonder if you had experienced this? The product image box on the right under “Add Product” seems to be missing (View https://nimb.ws/thSTYC). I tried online tutorial of deactivating plugins and changed to default Twenty Seventeen theme and nothing works. I even remove all my codes under functions.php and my all custom CSS that didn’t work either. Under Screen Options there’s no Product Image selection, https://nimb.ws/tlzjFy

However, featured image box appears to be visible for adding post.

Any ideas what else I should try?

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I eventually found the culprit, https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: I just ran into this problem and THANK YOU! I contacted woocommerce because I had disabled all the plugins and it wouldn't come back. but when i saw this, i disabled the plugin then checked the "Screen Options" at the top, I still had to enable the image, which I couldn't do. It worked a few days ago but there was a recent update, so this bug reappeared after a few years.