# Product image missing in WooCommerce admin

Tags: woocommerce

I have the same problem: [Product image box missing under WooCommerce admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57419159/product-image-box-missing-under-woocommerce-admin/61520272)
That was solved disabling the plugin Advance Custom fields but i dont have it.
I tried disablig all plugins but nothing changes.

Any idea?

Woocommerce 4

Thnx!

EDIT:

The problem is in admin product.
As in this reference [Product image box missing under WooCommerce admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57419159/product-image-box-missing-under-woocommerce-admin/61520272) y don’t have in right column the option of "product image".
I only have "product gallery". And under "Screen Options" there’s no Product image selection.

Comment: Can you provide more details? The question you reference is vague as it stands.

Comment: The problem is in admin product. As in this reference Product image box missing under WooCommerce admin y don’t have in right column the option of "product image". I only have "product gallery". And under "Screen Options" there’s no Product image selection. Thnx!

Comment: Have you set the Shop Page in (Woocommerce > Settings > Products - Shop Page with dropdown)?

Comment: Yes. All works fine, except that i can't choose the product image because i don't have it in admin in the right column